# Codeigniter Image Output don't work in different Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 Controller (CodeIgniter)

```
controllers
 - indexController.php
 - admin (Folder)
   - adminController.php
```

- IndexController is a SubClass of MY_Controller
- adminController is a SubClass of MY_Admin_Controller (and MY_Admin Controller is a SubClass of MY_Controller)

In both controller (index and admin) i have a function. This:

```
function thumb() {
    $product = $this->products->get_product_by_id($this->uri->segment(2));

    if($product == NULL) show_error("No Access", 403);

    $delimeter = "";
    if(stripos($product->thumbpath, "/") !== false) {
        $delimeter = "/";
    } else {
        $delimeter = "\"";
    }
    $arr = explode($delimeter, $product->thumbpath);

    $path = "uploads/".$this->uri->segment(2)."/".$arr[count($arr)-1];

    $this->load->image($path, get_mime_by_extension($path));

}
```

If i execute this function from the adminController - it does.
But if i execute this function from the indexController - it doesn't...

this is in my routes.php:

```
$route['thumb/:any'] = "index/thumb";
```

- from adminController i get a working image...
- from indexController i get a broken image....

There is actually no limit (session, file-permissions...)

Anyone - any idea what i can do?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the $path is wrong when you're in the index controller. Try this:

```
$path = base_url()."uploads/".$this->uri->segment(2)."/".$arr[count($arr)-1];
```

Honestly I find most links in CI easier to handle when I make them absolute paths using base_url rather than relative paths, also from my understanding absolute paths are better for SEO, although I can't attest to that being true.

Comment: the image functions uses relative paths. i solved the problem in another way. i pasted the function in a separate controller (not the indexController) - like a thumbController. i don't know why that works and the other not....